# Riemann integral $\underline{\int_a^b} \alpha f = \alpha \underline{\int_a^b} f$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, supremum-and-infimum, riemann-integration

During our introduction to Riemann integrals and Darboux sums we recieved we encountered this theorem:

> Let $f$ be a bounded function in $[a,b]$, Then if $\alpha >0$ then $\underline{\int_a^b} \alpha f = \alpha \underline{\int_a^b}  f$.

So far I've proven by contradiction that $$\alpha  \inf f  = inf (\alpha f)$$.

I've used this fact to show that for some partition $P$: $$L(\alpha f, P)= \alpha L(f,P)$$

But I'm not sure how to translate my findings to arguments regarding lower integarls.
$$ \underline{\int_a^b} \alpha f = \sup \,L( \alpha f,P) $$
and
$$ \alpha \underline{\int_a^b} = \alpha \sup \,L(f,P) $$

Comment: I think you want to use sup here because you are discussing lower Riemann integrals

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thank you for pointing this out. I used the wrong one for the lower integrals. but using inf for function values is still correct I think, because the Darboux sums use the infimum of each section of the partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each partition $P$, we have$$L(\alpha f,P)=\alpha L(f,P)$$and therefore\begin{align}\underline{\int_a^b}\alpha f&=\sup_PL(\alpha f,P)\\&=\sup_P\alpha L(f,P)\\&=\alpha\sup_PL(f,P)\\&=\alpha\underline{\int_a^b}f.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to address my questions! I would like to ask for clarification. Why does $ \sup_P\alpha L(f,P) = \alpha \sup_PL(f,P) $ ?  How can you take $\alpha$ out of the $\sup$ ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with integrals. If $\alpha\geqslant0$, if $S$ is a bounded set of real numbers and if $\alpha S=\{\alpha s\mid s\in S\}$, then [$\sup\alpha S=\alpha\sup S$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1516757/446262).

Answer (score 0):

You can take out $\alpha$ because of the following results.

Let $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a bounded collection of real numbers.
Then for every $\alpha \in [0,\infty)$ it holds the following:
$$\sup_I{\alpha x_i} = \alpha \sup_I{x_i}$$
Proof:
$$\alpha x_i \leq \alpha \sup_I {x_i}$$
for every $i$ so we can pass to the supremum and we get
$$\sup_I{\alpha x_i} \leq \alpha \sup_I{x_i}$$
For the converse inequality let $i^*$ be such that $\sup_I{x_i} - x_{i^*} < \frac{\epsilon}{\alpha}$
Now:
$$\alpha \sup_I {x_i} \leq \epsilon + \alpha x_{i^*} \leq \epsilon + \sup_I {\alpha x_i}$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we get:
$$\alpha \sup_I {x_i} \leq  \sup_I {\alpha x_i}$$